# Django : Generic Foreign key dumpdata: Can't resolve dependencies

Tags: django, generics, foreign-key-relationship, natural-key, dumpdata

I use Generic Foreign keys to relate different profiles with my `Users` model which is inherited from `auth.User`. I'm not able to do `dumpdata` though with the `--natural` option passed. It says,

*Error: Can't resolve dependencies for myproject.AdminProfile, myproject.TeacherProfile, myproject.Users in serialized app list.*

According to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.generic.GenericForeignKey), it's said that we need to implement [natural_key methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#topics-serialization-natural-keys) to take and flash fixtures which involves generic relations. How could I do that with my models presented here?

```
class Users(User):
    location = models.TextField('Location', blank=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='created_by_user')

    # Generic foreign key setup to hold the extra attributes
    profile_contenttype = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, null=True, blank=True)
    profile_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField('Extra ID', null=True, blank=True)
    profile_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('profile_contenttype', 'profile_object_id')


class AdminProfile(models.Model):
    organization = models.CharField('Organization', max_length=100)

    # profile reverse relation to get the user
    users_link = generic.GenericRelation('Users', content_type_field='profile_contenttype',
                                         object_id_field='profile_object_id')

class TeacherProfile(models.Model):
    designation = models.CharField('Designation', max_length=100)

    # profile reverse to get the user
    users_link = generic.GenericRelation('Users', content_type_field='profile_contenttype',
                                         object_id_field='profile_object_id')
```

Using Django 1.4.3 and Postrgres.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue seems unrelated to the absence of natural key methods. I tested your [original] code as-is on Django 1.4 and 1.2.5 using SQLite and was able to dump data with natural keys with no errors.

After some searching, I found that this issue appears when there are cyclic dependencies between models (including models with self-references). As your updated code shows, there's a self reference in the `Users` model, so that's where the problem is. This bug was introduced in Django 1.3 and, despite being [already fixed](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16317), it's still not available AFAIK in the stable versions (tested up to 1.4.3). In the beta version (1.5b2), however, your code works fine.

If using a beta version (or downgrading to 1.2) is not an option, then your only solution might be creating another model indeed. Something like:

```
class CreatedBy(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(Users, related_name="created_by_user")
    created = models.ForeignKey(Users, unique=True, related_name="created_by")
```

Comment: *I found that this issue appears when there are cyclic dependencies between models (including models with self-references)*. Thanks for the info. Actually I had a self-reference field. Sorry for not adding that first time(check the edit now). When I remove it I'm able to get the dump. But I need that field anyway. Is that possible? Or I have to create an another model to keep that ralation?

Comment: @Babu That's it then! Check my updated answer. Your code works fine in 1.2.5 and 1.5b2 (where this bug has already been fixed), but not in 1.4 (and I presume neither in 1.3).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer and multi-version test results. :) I'll go with creating an another model then. It's very weird and pity that it's not fixed in 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

The more general problem (circular dependencies involving natural keys, instead of just self-references with natural keys) is an open bug and reported here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31051